# Why Boolean modifier is not working

Tags: mesh, modifiers

I have 2 mesh and with the boolean modifier im making the difference but instead of making difference the inner side its making the difference to outer side. I have remove doubles and also give little thickness to the mesh.

[image]

[image]

[image]
Any suggestion or Help Thanks

Comment: Make sure that your normals are not inverted in any of the objects

Comment: @cegaton I have inverted the normal. ctrl+N. Plz go through my blend file attach

Comment: @atek please check my edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got your file, found the problem, and a possible solution.

First of all, the boolean is "disabled in viewport" (eye icon), so re-enable it. Then the problems were, imho:

1) the eight cutting meshes (doors?) have problems, faces are messed up, but we can correct them
2) the octagonal wall is not centered in the grid, and this caused misalignment with the above "doors", causing more trouble.

Below, look at your "doors-cutting" meshes in face select mode: some faces are apparently missing their "face-dots"!! This is for all eight shapes.

[image]

Here you can see the octagonal wall is not centered, and that "doors-cutting" meshes are wrongly positioned to cut the wall in the same way...

[image]

Now for the solution: select the wall and center it well on the grid, it will make easier the next.

[image]

Then Delete all but one of those "doors-cutting" meshes.

[image]

then delete also some vertices from the only one left.

[image]

As you can see now the wall is cut a door with the only "door-cutting" mesh.

[image]

Now we duplicate that door to get other "doors"... set transform pivot to "cursor" and put the cursor at grid center

[image]

then duplicate the cutting shapes and rotate them in position. Be careful to position them well.

[image]

And so, in the end you get all 8 well shaped doors...

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the detail answer problem is with my wrong extruding. Can you explain me as i have made the flat mesh of single door and how can i extrude it from both the end similar. The point where i gone wrong with the extruding. I have extruded half from front then half from back. Can you plz explain me how can i extrude from front and back same time.

Comment: mmm, afaik the extrusion is possible only in one direction at a time... in your eight shapes something was overlapped weirdly and that was the main issue, slight misalignment was a minor problem but it looks better with perfect simmetry, imho. I still can't get exactly how you did to extrude those shapes...

Answer (score 3):

On *"Curve.014"* mesh you have unnecessary overlapping **Edge Loop**, and this is why **Boolean** won't work. Just remove them and everything is ok.

[image: Edge loops]

[image: result]

Also consider making this mesh with quad topology as a good practice, it's pretty easy with this one. Or just don't bother if you don't need proper topology.

### Edit:

**Extruding both ways.**

With meshes without overlapping **Edge Loops** select both faces (front and back) and in the **Tools Panel** select **Extrude Individual** and move your mouse (or type in distance).

[image]

Comment: It was pretty simple mistake, it's working without any hassle ;) If you want to know how to extrude both ways at once I can show you in an edit.